# Functions indexed and declared in an Array, possibility and alternatives

Tags: javascript, json

I have some issues to organize my code.

Here is an example of what i would like to do:

```
var Test = {
  old: [
    get: function(who, when){
       returrn({ subject: "Old test 001", text: "The test 001 was perform by "+who });
    },
    get: function(who, when){
      returrn({ subject: "Old test 002", text: "The "+when+" the test 002 was performed"});
    }
  ],
  new: [
     //Same thing
  ]
};
```

The thing is, we apparently can't do that, so i am wondering which is the way to declare functions in an Array ? 
I need to do that because each method get() of the array can return a different message and the message can include the variables passed in parameters at different positions in the text, so i have to declare it explicitly.

I don't do like this:

```
var Test = {
  old: [
    one: {
      get: function(who, when){
        returrn({ subject: "Old test 001", text: "The test 001 was perform by "+who });
      },
    },
    two: {
      get: function(who, when){
        returrn({ subject: "Old test 002", text: "The "+when+" the test 002 was performed"});
      }
    }
  ],
  new: [
     //Same thing
  ]
};
```

Because i need to access the content dynamically, like `Test.old[test_id].get("toto", "02/04/2013")`. and we unfortunatelly can't index things by numerical values in JSON.

However i'll do it like this is there is nothing better.

So what is the best thing to do in this context ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is vague and confusing, but I can see why your code doesn't work. You're conflating arrays and objects. Array literals look like this:

```
var myArray = [
  "first item",
  "second item",
  {value: "third item"},
  ["first/only item in fourth item"],
  1,
  2,
  3.14159,
  function(a,b) { return a + b; },
  "etc."
];
```

Items in an array are accessed using push, pop, shift, unshift, and **numerical** indexes.

Object literal look like this:

```
var myObject = {
  one: "some value",
  two: {
    value: "object values can be anything"
  },
  123: 456,
  "a million": function (a, b) { return a - b; }
};
```

Items in an object are access using string indexes.

And finally, do you have a **returrn()** function declared somewhere? In either case, why not just **return** your *return* values?

Comment: Thanks, the third line from your array helped me to understand what i did wrong. To answer your question, i use return because when i call the data, i need it to be built about the arguments i send when i call it `Test.old[0].get(arg1, arg2);` and these args will be different to each calls.